# Trigger afterFind hooks on included models in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models. Purchase and PurchaseDetail and they are associated with
Purchase.hasMany(models.PurchaseDetail)
PurchaseDetail.belongsTo(models.Purchase)

I have the afterFind hook on PurchaseDetail that checks other models and adds data to the instance about the status of the product used in the PurchaseDetail and it works fine when I directly call PurchaseDetail.find

However, when I do Purchase.find and include PurchaseDetail, this hook is not triggered.

I know I can just call both models separately and combine it myself and send the data but if another developer in my team decides to include InvoiceDetail they will not receive this information.

How can I trigger this function anytime PurchaseDetail is included?

Comment: show us the code

Comment: See also this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4546.

Answer (score 2):

What we are doing here in the company I work for is extracting the behavior of the `afterFind` hook in child to a prototype function that we called `expand`, and then calling this `expand` function inside `afterFind` hook.

Then, we created an `afterFind` hook inside the parent entity, and inside that, called `child.expand()`.

Comment: Please share the code of what you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The `hooks` aren't called in other models (`findAll({ model, include: [{ model, include }]`)
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4627